# Router interface on same subnet

Tags: router, vlan, subnet, bridging

Could someone please explain why a router can't have 2 interfaces on same subnet?

Do routers use network addresses to forward traffic?

Comment: A router is deterministic; it must know where to send a packet based on the destination address. A router with two interfaces in the same network would not know which interface to use when forwarding packets to that network. Routers do not guess, they look through a routing table until a match is found for the destination address, so only one interface would be used for the network.

Comment: this match can have multiple entries. OSPF can use ECMP (equal cost multipath). EIGRP can have more options than equal cost.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

> why can't we have 2 interface on same subnet?

You can generally, some devices may have restrictions though. There are just very few situations where that makes sense.

A router forwards *in between* subnets, so multiple interfaces with the same subnet are rarely useful. (I'm referring to *logical* interfaces. Multiple *physical* interfaces commonly make sense when aggregating links, as @Peregrino69 has already pointed out, or for redundancy.)

> Do router use network address to forward traffic?

Yes, routers forward by a packet's destination network address (usually IP nowadays).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a *much* simplified explanation. This applies only in a situation where a router has 2 locally connected interfaces in the same subnet without link aggregation or other bonding method.

There are 2 types of networks and interfaces: physical and logical. A physical interface is the port where you plug a cable in, a physical network is the arrangement of physical devices connected to the network; usually in the same physical location. A logical interface is the IP address used to make forwarding decisions, a logical network is the subnet identified by network address. Logical networks can extend to multiple physical locations.

Assume you have a network 192.168.1.0/24. To route traffic to that network your router must have an interface connected to that network, and the interface must have an IP address. Like this:

```
                 -------------------------
                 | ROUTER                |
                 |       192.168.1.1 int1--------- 192.168.1.0/24 network
  INTERNET-------int0 10.10.10.10        |
                 -------------------------
```

The devices in the network will have a routing table instructing them to route all traffic to all unknown networks to IP address 192.168.1.1 (Default Gateway). The router will have a routing table showing:

```
Route all traffic to network 192.168.1.0/24 through physical interface int1 (alternatively logical interface 192.168.1.1)
Route all traffic to all other networks through physical interface int0 (alternatively logical interface 10.10.10.10)
```

Having 2 logical interfaces pointing to the same logical network (192.168.1.0/24) confuses things. Let's assume this situation:

```
WEB1 2.2.2.2/24
   |
   |
   |2.2.2.1/24
IROUTER
   |1.1.1.1/24
   |
   |                   LAN 192.168.1.0/24
---|----------------    --------------
| R0 1.1.1.2/24    |    |            | 
|                  |    |            |
| 192.168.1.1/24 R1------    SW1     ----PC1 
|                  |    |            |
| GWROUTER         |    --------------
|                  |    --------------
|                  |    |            |
| 192.168.1.2/24 R2------    SW2     ----PC2 
|                  |    |            |
--------------------    --------------
```

PC1 wants to access a website provided by WEB1 on IP address 2.2.2.2. The server is not in subnet 192.168.1.0/24, so it will send the packet to GWROUTER 192.168.1.1. It doesn't know where the server is either, but it knows that traffic to all unknown destinations must go to IROUTER 1.1.1.1 so it forwards the packet there. IROUTER has direct connection to subnet 2.2.2.0/24, so it will follow instruction "Forward all traffic to 2.2.2.0/24 through locally connected interface", whereupon it will reach the WEB1 server.

WEB1 sends a response. IROUTER doesn't know where the eventual target is, but it knows the request came from GWROUTER so it will forward the response to 1.1.1.2. GWROUTER receives it, and since it's directly connected to 192.168.1.0/24 it will follow instruction "Forward all traffic to 192.168.1.0/24 through locally connected interface".

But there are 2 locally connected interfaces to 192.168.1.0/24. Which one should be used to forward the response?

For redundancy and efficiency purposes there are ways to combine multiple physical interfaces so that they are presented as a single logical interface; for example LACP. Similarly there are ways to combine multiple logical interfaces to use to a single physical interface; for example configuring sub-interfaces to forward traffic to multiple VLANs.

Also it should be noted that any individual manufacturer may well have a solution for connecting one subnet may be via 2 individual logical interfaces, without any kind of bonding or link aggregation. However these are proprietary solutions, not applicable in general level.

Comment: What if 2 logical interface pointing 2 diffrent network like interface a :- 192.168.1.0/24 and interface b:- 192.168.5.0/24 will there be problem in this case?

Comment: *To route traffic to that network your router must have an interface connected to that network* - larger networks weren't possible like that. To route traffic to that network your router must *know a route* pointing to that network. The destination network can be behind other gateways. *the router might receive an ARP request on interface A, but route the response back through interface B* - it wouldn't ever do that.

Comment: @Rohit That is exactly the purpose of a router: forward between multiple interfaces connected to different subnets.

Comment: Rohit - no, in that case no problem. Network x.x.x.0/24 contains IP addresses from x.x.x.1 to x.x.x.255, so 192.168.1.0/24 and 192.168.5.0/24 are different networks, even if they were running on the same network hardware. @Zac67 - you're right, but I did specifically state my explanation's simplified :-) I'm referring to directly connected subnets. Sorry but couldn't come up with a better confusion example due to unbalanced blood levels in my caffeine :-P

Comment: But Zac67 in this website "https://learningnetwork.cisco.com/s/question/0D53i00000Ksv3l/two-interfaces-on-the-same-subnet" everyone is saying you can't have 2 interface with same subnet it would cause same problem as said by Peregrino69.

Comment: My ARP example wasn't a very good one... been a while since I've dealt with this question :-D I'm trying to figure out a better example and will amend my answer.

Comment: @Rohit The link refers to *overlapping* subnets which won't work in general (same or different interfaces). Overlapping subnets cannot work as the introduce ambiguity.

Comment: Could u please elaborate on this point "the router might receive an ARP request on interface A, but route the response back through interface B - it wouldn't ever do that."

Comment: @Zac67 mate, I think you're confusing poor OP even further :-D The link discusses exactly what they're asking - why having 2 separate IP interfaces in the same 10.1.0.0/16 subnet without link aggregation is a no-no. Situations when it *might* make sense are the odd exception to the general rule.

Comment: If we imagine pc having ip of 192.168.1.2 and pc 2 192.168.1.3 so if pc1 request for web 1 and router send all traffic to 1.1.1.1 but the request packet will have my Mac address which router will remember and when respose come from website it will forward to pc1 isn't it write?

Comment: Router forwards traffic based on IP, not MAC address.

Comment: @Rohit A host would never reply to an ARP request from another interface than the requested one. ARP replies aren't routed, they're an interface/binding function.

Comment: Thx @Zac67. Hope my updated example is a better one :-)

Comment: Rohit, 2 suggestions. 1) If you haven't already done so, register in https://www.netacad.com/ and download Cisco Packet Tracer. You can set up networks with PCs, and use the Simulation mode to see how exactly the traffic is being forwarded in the network, even if you won't be able to test this specific scenario there either. 2) Turn the question around: Why exactly would you want 2 interfaces to the same subnet? Is there a benefit you cannot achieve with the existing, robust redundancy protocols? :-)

Comment: Can't router remember the ip of pc1? Generally we connect to website based on port number like 5.6.7.9/4738 where 5.6.7.9 is my router public ip. Is what I am saying is right?

Comment: Sure. It even knows it needs to forward the response packet to the locally connected network. Again: Why?

Comment: Thanks buddy for clearing my doubt. Will get back to u later 

Comment: in this example, PC1 and PC2 cannot reach each other (unless the router also acts as L2 switch and can forward l2 traffic between these two interfaces). if there was a link between SW1 and SW2, then the router could send its data from either interface and it will be delivered to PC1.

Comment: In theory, could, if router logic allowed "if two interfaces to the same subnet use either" (they don't)  *and* if the switches have a direct connection - would router be able to know? It could be argued that the second interface could work as a backup DGW, but that'd require re-writing router sofwares *and* NIC drivers. Should we allow limitless individual, equal routing interfaces to a single subnet? Would that change in routing logic prevent other potential issues, or maybe introduce funky new ones? And still - what benefit would we get over current redundancy protocols? :-)

Comment: the router should not care if two switches have a direct connection. if this direct connection does not exist than your subnet is partitioned, i.e., it should not be a single subnet. And if this subnet is not partitioned, the router can send a packets through either of this interfaces and it would not matter which one.

Comment: I clearly say that my example is simplified. I was bringing it down to the OP:s level of knowledge. This isn't about physical connectivity. This is the third time the OP asked the same question. Quoting: "If imagine lan assigned ip from from this range (192.168.1.0/24) then can we assign another ip from same subnet mask? If no why?" "Can the router's ethernet interface have multiple IP's of the same subnet". The generally accepted answer is "no". Are you categorically stating that everyone who thinks so - including all router manufacturers who don't allow such configuration - is wrong?

Comment: i am categorically stating that they don't allow such configuration for reasons that have nothing to do with forwarding.

Comment: @effenok 1. What exactly are those reasons? 2. Why is that talking about *basic* routing - *not* *advanced* *capabiliities* *of* *enterprise-level* *routers*- it is generally accepted fact to be a bad idea? 3. Can you point to a single resource that would recommend such configuration - if not, why not?

Comment: 1. i can't answer this in general, they are protocol specific. OSFP stuff is here: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2328#appendix-F  (we can discuss it but not in comments). 3. i do not know the answer to this question. if every manufacturer disallows such configuration, than it is probably a bad idea. 2. i don't think this question is basic routing, unless the author actually asked something else.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129379/discussion-between-peregrino69-and-effenok).

Answer (score 1):

1. a router can be physically connected to the same subnetwork with different interfaces.
2. routers, that implement dynamic routing protocols, may not work if a single router has two interfaces facing the same subent. This has something to do with how information is exchanged and how shortest paths are calculated. Thus a routing protocol may not support a situation where two interfaces are connected to the same subnet. I.e., this protocol will do something incorrectly if this happens. Examples:

   - [OSPF RFC, Appendix F](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2328#appendix-F) more or less says that you actually can. You have to specially configure the router, and from what i read, configuration error can cause incorrect behavior.
   - here is a [link](https://blog.ipspace.net/2008/10/ospf-breaks-when-faced-with-overlapping.html) testing simple configuration with two interfaces having the same subnet with RIP, EIGRP, and OSPF. According to the link, both RIP and EIGRP work, however IOS version of OSPF fails to compute correct routes
   - this applies to bridges/switches too. STP in particular specifies how to handle situation where two interfaces are connected to the same LAN. In this case the bridge selects one based on this interface identifier.
3. there is nothing related to forwarding that prevents a router to have two interfaces on the same subnetwork. There is nothing special in a situation where a router has several interfaces that can route  traffic to the same destination, and this case is a special case of such situation.

   3.1. first, there is usually more than one physical network path between a given router and a given destination, and different paths go through different interfaces (or different routers which are connected through the same interface, this happens e.g., if routers are connected to the same subnet). The goal of a shortest path routing protocol is to select the best one (based on cost/metric). While doing so it also selects the interface that this path goes through.

   3.2 it also can happen that there are several paths with the same cost. in this case there are two options: a) router selects one (it does not matter which one) , b) router distributes traffic between them all - this is known as Equal Cost Multi-Path (ECMP). AFAIK at least most intra-domain protocols do option b.

Comment: Re 2. Not all routers by far implement a routing protocol (like RIP, OSPF, IS-IS, BGP). Re 2.3 *switches* are a totally different situation this question isn't about. Re 3.1 Different paths don't necessarily use different egress interfaces. They might just use a different next hop. Likewise, re 3.2 ECMP can use fewer interfaces than there are paths.

Comment: re 2. what do you mean by routers not implement a routing protocol.? re 3.1/3.2 i added a clarify, but the point is - a single address in a forwarding table can have multiple interface/next hop pairs. this is specified behavior. in this case the router can choose any entry to forward packet to (in theory, in practice router should make sure to select the same entry for packets of the same flow to avoid reordering).

Comment: OSPF etc. are *optional* routing protocols for dynamic route exchange. Basic routers use static routing *without* a routing protocol. For 3.2, use should make that "that there are several *paths* with the same cost". Whether or not ECMP is used depends on a router's capabilities and its configuration, not on any protocol.

Comment: if you use static routing then you can configure your router so it works correctly (or do not use one of the interfaces); Whether on not ECMP is used depends on both. in order to use ECMP your protocol should be capable of computing multiple paths. Then it also should be capable of supporting multiple next hops in forwarding tables, and then it can be configured not to do so.

Comment: A nice writeup. But are you absolutely convinced the OP possesses sufficient understanding to grasp advanced topics like OSPF or ECMP? Or would it be advisable to build a bit of basic knowledge first? Also STP is irrelevant since the whole discussion is only about multiple independent, equal routing interfaces leading into the same subnet *without* any kind of link aggregation *or* redundancy methods in any level.

Comment: half of the comments here say that routers cannot deal with it because of some version - "forwarding is ambiguous". This is wrong and I have to explain why it is. And i don't know how to explain it in any less advanced terms.

Comment: Um... so you *are* actually saying you're right, everyone else is wrong. I don't even know what to say to that.

Comment: Routing protocols do not route, they exchange routing information. Routers route by what is in their routing tables, and routing protocols are one of three ways to populate a routing table. Not all routing information gathered by routing protocols need to make it out of the routing protocol tables into the routing table, For example, a routing protocol may get routing information from another router about a network directly connected to the receiving router, but that routing information, while in the routing protocol table, will not override the directly connected information of the router.

Comment: @RonMaupin where did i say, that routing protocol routes?

Comment: The implication of "_a router implements a routing protocol._" that your answer started when I wrote the comment is just that. Routers route, even without routing protocols. Even the "_there is nothing related to forwarding that prevents a router to have two interfaces on the same subnetwork._" is normally incorrect. It is highly unusual for a router to be able to do that, which is recognized in RFC 6598 and why CGN is for ISPs, not regular businesses or home networks. Routers route between networks, not from a network back to the same network.

Comment: @RonMaupin is this "normally incorrect" related to forwarding, where forwarding is specifically the function that specifies how a router forwards a packet given its destination address and content of the forwarding table?

Answer (score 0):

> Could someone please explain why a router can't have 2 interfaces on same subnet?

As others pointed out, you can.  My answer explains the typical terminology associated with this function.

Using the example of Cisco Systems products, this is normally called either an [SVI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_virtual_interface) or [bridging](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/bridge/info) (depending on the model of the device in question).

- An [SVI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_virtual_interface) just defines puts all the "same subnet" traffic in one [VLAN](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/vlan/info); the traffic within the same VLAN should be handled in hardware (very quickly)
- [Bridging](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/bridge/info) is generally slower and punted to the CPU for each packet; if you do this, be sure you know how much traffic will be sent through the bridge so you don't overload your CPU.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have the same subnet on 2 interfaces I did use the Bridge.

By the way, Virtual machines often create a virtual bridge in host OS to connect physical network with virtual network.

Comment: Unfortunately, hosts/servers/VMs are off-topic here. The question is about a router (enterprise-grade routers are on-topic here).